# How Do I determine request time out of my kafka producer?

Tags: apache-kafka

if I have a kafka producer on a live machine which writes its data to a kafka topic. What happens when there is a network issue or kafka goes down which would simultaneously affect the performance of the live machine by request-timeout set as kafka producer would time out after request timeout millisecs set for each send request requested by the live machine.

Comment: Did you write the producer code yourself?

Comment: No I am using the kafka producer API in which I have to set request time out for my live machine producer.

Comment: If it exists, it will be on this list. http://kafka.apache.org/documentation.html#producerconfigs

Comment: @morganw09dev I am not looking for the property , I am interested in the best value to be set

Comment: 27??? In all seriousness, your question is very unclear as to what you asking for. At no point do you say your want the best value. I think you should revise your question.

Comment: @krishat of course you're using the API, but you're not using it from the thin air, you must have wrote a piece of code that uses it or you use e.g. Kafka Console Producer, Logstash, Fluentd, or any other message shipper that uses the Producer API below the covers. That was the question.

Comment: BTW, I agree with @morganw09dev, 27 seems like a nice number :)

Comment: Ok Let me k=make my question clear ...

Comment: Ok Let me make my question clear ... if I have an application A which writes to  a kafka cluster  using kafka producer api (producer.send) . The producer  on application A needs to be configured with request.timeout.ms so that it does not effect the performance of the application A waiting to write on kafka when kafka goes down.

Comment: It's hard to specify any number like this. If I were you, I'd set up a test environment where I would simulate network partition and try out different options. Keep in mind that other params may also have influence on how timeout behaves (e.g. buffer size, required acks).